# Find the number of spanning trees

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Wo consider the graph $G$ that we get by deleting any edge from the complete bipartite graph $K_{7,8}$. How many spanning trees does the complement graph $\overline{G}$ of $G$ have?

I have thought the following:

The graph $K_{7,8}$ has $7^{8-1} \cdot 8^{7-1}$ spanning trees.

Then $G$ has $6^{7-1} \cdot 7^{6-1}$ spanning trees.

Does $\overline{G}$ have $7^{8-1} \cdot 8^{7-1}-6^{7-1} \cdot 7^{6-1}$ spanning trees. But, the result that we get isn't a possible one. So is my idea wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that $G$ has $6^{7-1} \cdot 7^{6-1}$ spanning trees? $G$ doesn't become a $K_{6,7}$ after deleting one of the edges, so you can't use that formula. To find the number of spanning trees on $G$ you need to find the number of spanning trees of $K_{7,8}$ using the deleted edges and subtract that from the total number of spanning trees of $K_{7,8}$.

To calculate the latter you can use the symmetry of $K_{7,8}$ and realize that deletion of any edges will result in removing the same amound of spanning trees. So now we have $7\cdot8 = 56$ edges and each spanning three contains $7+8-1=14$ edges and hence each edge is contained in $\frac{8^{6}\cdot 7^{7}}{7\cdot 8} \cdot 14=2\cdot8^5\cdot7^7$ spanning tree.  Hence $G$ has $8^{6}\cdot 7^{7} - 2\cdot8^5\cdot7^7 = 4\cdot8^5\cdot7^7$ spanning trees.

On the other side $\overline{G}$ can't be calculated as a difference between the spanning trees of $K_{7,8}$ and the spanning trees of $G$. Nevertheless if you draw $\overline{G}$ you will see it consists of two complete graphs $K_7$ and $K_8$ connected by an edge. Hence total number of spanning trees of $\overline{G}$ is $8^6\cdot 7^5$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: What *is* the graph $\overline G$?

Each of the bipartite parts of $G$ corresponds to what in $\overline G$? And how many edges connect the two?

Comment: At $\overline{G}$ only two vertices are conntected to each other. Right? @Arthur

Comment: @Evinda So you're saying $\overline G$ has $15$ vertices and only one edge? Or do you mean something else?